# Primitive recursive functions of bounded sum

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion, incompleteness

I'm reading "Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition" (by Elliott Mendelson) and confused at Proposition 3.17 (page 179), which is about primitive recursion obtained from bounded sum. I understand the proposition, which states that if $f(x_1,...,x_n, y)$ is primitive recursive, then the bounded sum $g(x_1,...,x_n, z) = \sum_{y<z}f(x_1,...,x_n, y)$ is also primitive recursive. The proof is simple and straightforward.

Now my question is: what if in the summation the value of $f$ also depends on $z$? That is to say, is $g(x_1,...,x_n, z) = \sum_{y<z}f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z)$ also primitive recursive?

The author gave an example (page 179), $\tau(x) = \sum_{y \leq x} \overline{sg}(rm(y, x))$, and claims that it is primitive recursive. It seems that it can be proved directly from Proposition 3.17. But it does not appear so, as $\overline{sg}(rm(y, x))$ is a function $f(x, y)$ that also depends on $x$.

One way to resolve this issue seems to be: if in the summation $\sum_{y<z}f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z)$ the function $f$ is obtained by "recursion on $z$", i.e. $f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z)$ depends on $f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z-1)$ which also depends on $f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z-2)$ and so on, then we can find a function $h(x_1,..., x_n, y) = f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z)$. It means we can eliminate the dependency on $z$ and $h$ is also primitive recursive.

The above method only applies to certain cases. Is the general case true?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the dependency of $f$ on $z$ and the dependency of the sum on $z$ are independent $\ddot{\smile}$. I.e., you can define

$$h(x_1,...,x_n, z_1, z_2) = \sum_{y<z_2}f(x_1,...,x_n, y, z_1)$$

and then define

$$g(x_1,...,x_n, z) = h (x_1,...,x_n, z, z)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I learned we can "construct" a primitive recursive function in such a devious way :-)